# Left-right topology

Tags: gauge-theory, symmetry-breaking, topology, magnetic-monopoles, solitons

Are there non-trivial topological solutions (in particular 't Hooft-Polyakov magnetic monopoles) associated with the (local) breaking

\begin{equation}
SU(2)_R \times SU(2)_L \times U(1)_{B-L} \to SU(2)_L \times U(1)_Y
\end{equation}

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a theory to present stable monopole solutions it has to satisfy three requirements:

i) It has to have the topological conditions, generally showed as non trivial [second homotopy group](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotopyGroup.html) of the vacuum manifold.

ii) It has to satisfy a quantization condition
$$e^{ieQ_m}=\mathbb 1,$$
where $Q_m$ is the (non-Abelian) magnetic charge. This is a generalization of the [Dirac quantization condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Dirac.27s_quantization).

iii) The monopole has to be a solution of the classical equations of montion.

It can be shown that to satisfy ii) the $U(1)_{em}$ has to be compact (the electric charge has to quantized as well), that is, isomorphic to the circle and not to the reals. It turns out that when you have a SSB $G\rightarrow K\times U(1)$, the $U(1)$ is compact if $G$ and $K$ are both [semisimple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleLieAlgebra.html). Otherwise $U(1)$ may be non compact. In your case, $G$ is not semisimple, it has an Abelian factor.

For chiral symmetry breaking such as in QCD where the symmetry is global there are definitely no 't Hooft-Polyakov monopoles since those appear when you spontaneously break a local gauge symmetry. You are breaking a global one.

There are some studies about something called "[semilocal defects](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9206216)" that may appear when you break a local and a global symmetry in a "mixed way".

What characterizes the stability of topological solutions as monopoles and vortices are topological quantities as the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number). Take a vortex, for simplicity. Roughly speaking the winding number would say how the scalar field rotate as we go around the vortex. This rotation is in the internal space. With a global symmetry you are not able to construct such a rotating scalar field. The topological numbers would be trivial.